# KONG API GW. How to redirect http response to https

Tags: google-chrome, http, kubernetes, https, kong

We have back end services for file transferring to ui. However our structure is layered where UI makes https requests to get related file and and A back-end service makes an http request to another back-end service. Then response is sent as a http stream. Therefore, we get network failed error on Chrome but not firefox. Here is the simple structure of existing flow. [image]

How can we overcome this failed network error? We think that reason is https request is responded with http stream. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any difference between https and http's response. I have a lot of use cases for https request but http respone.

The response header of "curl -X GET "http://httpbin.org/anything"  -v" and "curl -X GET "https://httpbin.org/anything"  -v" are exactly same.

Have you ever check the error log of kong?

Answer (score 0):

i was configuring the ingres in Kong like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    #configuration.konghq.com: https-only
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: konga
    kong.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    kong.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    kong.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kong.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"
    kong.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: konga-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: konga.test.tk
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: konga
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - konga.test.tk
    secretName: konga
```

in the background, i used to send the plain HTTP request and `SSL termination` occur at the `API gateway` or we can say `ingress` level. You can also check the logs of Kong deployment it might be due to **Timeout** issue or **size** limit.

i was using kong as ingress controller however you can change the config as per need in background if you are running as controller or API gateway.